# Adding a network folder to Clementine library

Tags: 12.04, server, networking, sharing, clementine

I have 2 machines running Ubuntu.  One of them contains a music library on its windows partition.

I can connect to that computer's music library via 'connect to server' and save that location as a bookmark, but I can't figure out a way to add that folder/bookmark to my Clementine library.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have something more complicated?
Just for a simple mortal?
Something like any basic computer user could...use?

Answer (score 4):

Just found this post before but found easier solution for Ubuntu 12.10.

So to share for anyone else looking...

Ubuntu stores network shares as a folder in `/run/user/<user-name>/gvfs/<share-name>`

In Clementine just add that share folder.
Saves a lot of time.

In 12.04 I think it is `/home/<user-name>/.gvfs/<share-name>` but not sure if Clementine will see hidden folders worth a shot though.

Comment: You should consider adding a link to the original post/solution. (And a hidden folder is just a folder like any other, the difference is that its name starts with a dot.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by sharing the source Music folder with Samba, and have the remote machine automount the share to the local Music folder.

**On the Machine that has the music files**:

1. Setup Samba server.
2. Define a share at `~/Music` (or wherever your music files are located).

**On the Remote Machine**:

1. Install smbfs
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` to mount the share to `~/Music` (or anywhere else you want). [**Instructions**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)
3. Add the folder that the share is mounted to to Clementine Library.

A similar solution can be done with ssh/sshfs, if you need a more security.

Answer (score 1):

Update here.  Hope that someone finds this usefull.
On Linux Mint Mate Desktop Ulyana 20.00  using gio:

gio mount smb://server-name/share-name

will mount share in:

```
/run/user/value/gvfs/'smb-share:server=server name,share=share name'
```

I tested this as well on my latitude e6420 running Ubuntu focal with Mate desktop, the same results.

Comment: LM is off topic here.

Comment: @mikewhatever did you actually read the whole post?